# Android two countdown timer overlaps; How to delay the second one?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, timer, countdowntimer

My code consists of 2 countdown timers, one after finishing says GO! then the other one starts, however the second timer starts immediately, and the GO! message disappears immediately, how to delay the GO! message or the appearing of the second timer? Here's the code.

```
public class WorkoutGymEasy1 extends Activity {

CountDownTimer cdt = null;
MediaPlayer mp = null;
TextView c;
Button b;
ImageView image;
TextView pushuptext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workout_gym_easy1);
    final TextView c = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer_gym_easy1);
    c.setAlpha(0f);
    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setAlpha(1f);
    final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePushUp);
    b.setAlpha(1f);
    final TextView pushuptext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPushUp);
    b.setAlpha(1f);

    RelativeLayout rl5 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl5);
    rl5.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

     mp = MediaPlayer.create(WorkoutGymEasy1.this, R.raw.countdown);
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (View v) {
                b.setAlpha(0f);
                c.setAlpha(1f);
                mp.start();
                new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) { //20 seconds count down with 1s interval (1000 ms) //access TextView element on the screen to set the timer value
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { // Code in this method is executed every 1000ms (1s)
                        c.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished / 1000) + ""); //update the timer
                        //if (millisUntilFinished == 0) {
                            //c.setText("GO!");
                        //}
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        c.setText("GO!");
                        // Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutGymEasy2.class);
                        // startActivity(myIntent);
                        new CountDownTimer(31000, 1000) { //30 seconds count down with 1s interval (1000 ms) //access TextView element on the screen to set the timer value
                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { // Code in this method is executed every 1000ms (1s)
                                c.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished / 1000) + ""); //update the timer
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutGymEasy2.class);
                                startActivity(myIntent);

                                finish();               // call finish() method to destroy this activity and return to instructions screen
                            }
                        }.start();
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });

}

protected void OnPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mp.release();
    finish();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need 3 timers to simulate a delay. So the first timer would start and finish. Starting the "Go" timer. Then when the "Go" timer is finish, the second official timer would go off.